# How to adjust Request Content-Length with a Proxy that modifies content?

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty

Is it possible to change the Content-Length of an HttpServletRequest?

Can it be done with the [AsyncMiddleManServlet](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncMiddleManServlet.html)?

Comment: Check out the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767239/how-to-change-the-http-response-content-length-header-in-java-filter

Comment: Sorry but the posted link doesen´t help. Because there is described how to edit the HttpServletResponse not the HttpServletRequest!

Comment: Change it why? It is up to the client to define the content-length of the request. It doesn't make sense for the server to change it, unless it also changes the content.

Comment: I need to change the Length of the Content because the Body is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `AsyncMiddleManServlet` properly, then the `Content-Length` request header will be appropriately adjusted.

Comment: How do i use the AsyncMiddleManServlet properly? There is no Tutorial or help in the Internet.