# JAX-RS Jersey return content-length on every endpoint

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, jax-rs

We are trying to return content-length on a server running JAX-RS on every endpoint.

There are already some solutions based on adding the information on each endpoint, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24574405/3128369). However, this implementation is not very convenient as it requires editing each and every endpoint.

Is there a more straightforward way to make Jersey return content-length on every endpoint?

We also found [this potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11777977/3128369), but we are not sure how to generate a `ServletResponseWrapper`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS implementations by default add a Content-Length header if your endpoints have the following signature:

```
@GET
public SomeEntity get () {
    return X;
}
```

If you want, you can use Servlet filters because JAX-RS is built on top of servlets.

The only case where JAX-RS does not add a Content-Length header is if I return StreamingOutput.